# How can I edit a variable in a running shell?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm editing my PS1 prompt and I don't want to keep sourcing my bashrc to update it (since my bashrc resets other things too). I also don't want to copy and paste it over and over. Is there a way to edit the variable interactively, like using `nano` (my default editor)?

The PS1 is mostly an example, because I want to do the same thing with other vars. The reason I want to do it interactively is that the variable is already quite long, and I just need to edit a few characters in it. And I only need to change it in the current shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zsh has a builtin called `vared` that lets you edit a variable inline. I wrote my own version, originally posted [on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1316025/443564):

```
vared(){
    # Based on the zsh builtin of the same name.
    IFS= read -rei "${!1}" "$1"
}
```

Note this has some subtle differences from the Zsh builtin, e.g:

- Won't error if the variable is unset
- Checks the validity of the variable name *before* printing its value (e.g. `vared $`)
- Truncates multi-line variables.

Then to edit the PS1, just run `vared PS1`.

Comment: Accepting this answer cause it's what I use most day-to-day

Answer (score 9):

This can be done. Type `var=$var` and then expand and edit it. To expand,
use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> (the default shortcut, check output of `bind -p | grep shell-expand-line` to confirm).

So:

```
muru@muru-1604:~$ PS1=$PS1
```

will become:

```
muru@muru-1604:~$ PS1=${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

Which you can then edit in an editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> (`edit-and-execute-command` in readline terms). When you save and quit, the saved content will be executed by the shell.

If you already have `PS1=...` in your history, you can just go back to that and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands):

> `shell-expand-line (M-C-e)`
>
> Expand the line as the shell does. This performs alias and history
>   expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions.
>
> `edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)`
>
> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result
>   as shell commands. Bash attempts to invoke $VISUAL, $EDITOR, and emacs
>   as the editor, in that order.

Comment: Nice! Just Esc, Ctrl+E is exactly what I was looking for. Though when I typed `PS1='$PS1'`, it deleted the quotes, but typing `PS1=\'$PS1\'` works perfectly.

Comment: And reading through `bind -p`, I also found out you can expand globs, tildes, and history lines. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sourcing the bashrc, source another file, which just contains the variable.

1. Create it:

   ```
   echo "PS1='$PS1'" > /tmp/PS1
   ```

   - Note: If the variable contains single quotes, you will need to use a command that can escape them, e.g.:

     ```
     declare -p PS1 | cut -d' ' -f3- > /tmp/PS1
     ```
2. Open it in an editor, e.g. `nano /tmp/PS1`.

   - To avoid running `nano` over and over, you could run it in another terminal/TTY, or use a graphical editor.
3. Make your changes and save.
4. Source it:

   ```
   source /tmp/PS1
   ```
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 as needed.